# Como mostrar un solo registro en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo, se conecta a la base de datos y ejecuta un query y este lo almaceno en `result2` hasta ahi esta todo bien, pero a la hora que me imprime los registros yo deseo que nomas imprima un solo registro de solo la fecha y hora y no los de hora con minutos.

Alguien podria guiarme a encontrar una solucion.

```
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>fecha</th>
            <th>Hora</th>

            <th>Int</th>        
            <th>
                <p>Escoger Todos</p>
                <input  type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
            </th>
        </tr>

<?php

  if($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
     do
      {
      $cuenta_eventos++;             

?>

 <tr> 
   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["nombre"]);?></th>
   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["fecha"]);?></th>
   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["hora"]);?></th>

   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["int"]);?></th>  

   <th><p>Escoger Evento</p><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="<?php printf("%s",$myrow["nombre"]);?>"></th>
 </tr>

 <?php     
      }while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
   }else {
         } 

 ?>
```

Me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Nombre     |   Fecha        |   Hora      |   Int

SANT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:00:00'  |     1m
FNAT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:00:00'  |     1m
FNAT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:07:00'  |     1m
FNAT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:016:00' |     1m
```

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

```
Nombre     |   Fecha        |   Hora      |   Int

SANT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:00:00'  |     1m
FNAT       |   2016-10-03   | '03:00:00'  |     1m
```

Comment: ¿no quieres imprimir los minutos o los *segundos*?

Comment: @MitsuG no, solo las horas. asi como muestro en el ejemplo del resultado que deseo obtener

Comment: Solo te basta hacer: `date('H', $date).":00:00";`. Donde `$date` es la fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te han comentado con antes, con el `date` y el parámetro `H`, ya obtienes el resultado, quedando tu código de la siguiente manera

```
      <tr class="header">
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>fecha</th>
            <th>Hora</th>

            <th>Int</th>        
            <th>
                <p>Escoger Todos</p>
                <input  type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
            </th>
        </tr>

<?php

  if($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
     do
      {
      $cuenta_eventos++;             

?>

 <tr> 
   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["nombre"]);?></th>
   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["fecha"]);?></th>
   <th><?php printf("%s",date('H', $myrow["hora"]).":00:00";);?></th>

   <th><?php printf("%s",$myrow["int"]);?></th>  

   <th><p>Escoger Evento</p><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="<?php printf("%s",$myrow["nombre"]);?>"></th>
 </tr>

 <?php     
      }while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
   }else {
         } 

 ?>
```

Lo que no me ha quedado claro es si quieres que solo te muestre un registro, en cuyo caso a la consulta SQL, debes añadir al final `LIMIT 1`, o quieres mostrar todos, y solo modificar la hora.

Comment: era un simple `LIMIT` lo que ocupaba

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener solo la hora basta usar el formato `H` para parsear la fecha y luego rellenarlo con `:00:00`:

```
$time = strtotime($myrow["hora"]);
$hour = date('H', $time).":00:00";
```